# Log in log out session php

Tags: php, session

I have here the code of my login  and logout can you guys check if the session I placed is correct?

**Login code**:

```
<?php
session_start();

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Content-Type: text/html');

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysql_select_db("store_data", $connection);

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $admin=$_POST['user'];
    $pass=$_POST['pass'];
    $select_user = mysql_query("SELECT admin_name FROM admin");
    $select_pass = mysql_query("SELECT admin_pass FROM admin");
    $result_1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_user);
    $result_2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_pass);

    if($admin !=$result_1['admin_name'] || $pass!=$result_2['admin_pass']){
        echo "<script >alert('Invalid password or username')</script>";
        header("refresh:0; url=administrator.php" );
    }
```

**Logout code**:

```
<?php

session_destroy();
header("Location: administrator.php");

?>
```

Comment: You need to start session `session_start();` before `session_destroy();` in `LOGOUT CODE:`

Comment: You didn't created a session while logging in. fine in the case of logout

Comment: Why not just try and run your code and see if it works? If it doesn't then debug.

Answer (score 0):

Before `session_destroy` you need `session_start`

```
<?php    
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location: administrator.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Errors**

1. `session_start()` missing in logout
2. You **not check `$admin` and `$pass` value** in your query
3. Your **Argument is wrong** in the set session
4. And you **not setting any session to destroy** it
5. Don't use **MySQL Function Its depreciated now**

**In logout**

```
<?php
    session_start(); //add this
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: administrator.php");
?>
```

**In login**

```
<?php

    session_start();

    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header('Content-Type: text/html');

    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    $db = mysql_select_db("store_data", $connection);

    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        $admin=$_POST['user'];
        $pass=$_POST['pass'];

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin where admin_name='$admin' AND admin_pass = '$pass' ");

        $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        $count = count($result);

        if(!empty($count))
        {
            $_SESSION["admin_name"] = $admin;
            header("refresh:0; url=administrator.php" );
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Invalid User";
        }
    }
```